# Add custom options to dropdown via code in Magento

Tags: magento

i had to add custom options automatically when a product is added , the code works fine but i need to create a drop down menu with options and i dont know how to add options to the drop down created ,
  my code is

```
public function Add_CustomOptions_Automatically($observer) {
    $product = $observer->getEvent()->getProduct();
    $save = false; if (!$product->getOptions()) $save = true;

    $optionData = array(
        'previous_group'    => 'text',
        'title'             => 'Size',
        'type'              => 'drop_down',
        'is_require'        => 0,
        'sort_order'        => 0,
        'price'             => 0,
        'price_type'        => 'fixed');    


    if($save):
        $product->setHasOptions(1)->save();
        $option = Mage::getModel('catalog/product_option')
                    ->setProductId($product->getId())
                    ->setStoreId($product->getStoreId())           
                    ->addData($optionData);

        $option->save();
        $product->addOption($option);
    endif;
}
```

}

I've created `'type' => 'drop_down'` but how can I add options? I have no idea how to add the options, and any help would be very much appreciated.

thanks,

Answer (score 4):

You can supply an array of values to the option array, this will then be added
to the option. as below :-)

```
$product = Mage::getModel('catalog/product');
$product->load(200); // product id here

$opt = array(
    'is_delete'         => 0,
    'is_require'        => false,
    'previous_group'    => '',
    'title'             => 'New Example Option',
    'type'              => 'drop_down',
    'price_type'        => 'fixed',
    'price'             => '20.0000',
    'sort_order'        => 0,
    /** array of values for this option **/
    'values'            => array(
        array(
            'is_delete'     => 0,
            'title'         => 'Option One Here',
            'price_type'    => 'fixed',
            'price'         => 999,
            'sku'           => 'test-sku-here',
            'option_type_id'=> -1,
        ),
        array(
            'is_delete'     => 0,
            'title'         => 'Another Option',
            'price_type'    => 'fixed',
            'price'         => 999,
            'sku'           => 'another-sku-here',
            'option_type_id'=> -1,
    )),
);

$option = Mage::getModel('catalog/product_option')
    ->setProduct($product)
    ->addOption($opt)
    ->saveOptions();
```

Answer (score 2):

```
public function Add_CustomOptions_Automatically($observer) {
    $product = $observer->getEvent()->getProduct();

    $optionData = array(
        'previous_group'    => 'text',
        'title'             => 'Size',
        'type'              => 'drop_down',
        'is_require'        => 0,
        'sort_order'        => 0,
        'price'             => 0,
        'price_type'        => 'fixed');

    if(!(bool)$product->getOptions()):
        $product->setHasOptions(true)->save();
        $option = Mage::getModel('catalog/product_option')
                    ->setProductId($product->getId())
                    ->setStoreId($product->getStoreId())           
                    ->addData($optionData);

        // Answer starts here
        $value = Mage::getModel('catalog/product_option_value');
        $value->setOption($option)
              ->setTitle('Hello world!');
        $option->addValue($value);
        // Answer ends here

        $option->save();
        $product->addOption($option);
    endif;
}
```

As you can see you are adding a `Mage_Catalog_Model_Product_Option_Value` with a title and associating it with the `$option` you created. It can also have an SKU, price and sort order. Create as many values as you want in this way.

Answer (score 0):

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-W3CDTD XHTML 1.0 TransitionalEN" "http:www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http:www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
</head>
<body>
<pre>
<?php
$res = mysql_pconnect('localhost', 'your data base name', 'passward');
mysql_select_db('your database name');
mysql_query("SET NAMES 'utf8';", $res);
mysql_query("SET CHARACTER SET 'utf8';", $res);
$query = 'select entity_id from catalog_product_entity';
$res = mysql_query($query);
$products=array();
while ($ret = mysql_fetch_array($res)) {
  $products[]=$ret[0];
  $query = "UPDATE catalog_product_entity set has_options=1 where entity_id=$ret[0]";
  //echo "$query<br>";
  //$res1 = mysql_query($query);
}
echo "Set all products for has_options in catalog_product_entity.<br>";
//$res = mysql_query('DELETE from catalog_product_option');
//$res = mysql_query('DELETE from catalog_product_option_title');
//$res = mysql_query('DELETE from catalog_product_option_type_price');
//$res = mysql_query('DELETE from catalog_product_option_type_title');
//$res = mysql_query('DELETE from catalog_product_option_type_value');
echo "Deleted all rows from catalog_product_option* tables.<br>";

$ress=array();
foreach ($products as $product){
  $query = "insert into catalog_product_option (product_id,type,is_require,image_size_x,image_size_y,sort_order) values ($product,'drop_down',0,0,0,0)";
  echo "$query<br>";
  $res1 = mysql_query($query);
  $ress[] = array("option_id" => mysql_insert_id());
}
echo '<pre>';
print_r($ress);


echo "Populated catalog_product_option.<br>";
$option_titles=array('en_US'=> 'Warrenty' );// here change title of option titles #Optional Coating

$res = mysql_query('SELECT * FROM `core_config_data` WHERE path="general/locale/code"');
while ($ret = mysql_fetch_array($res)) {
  $stores[$ret['value']][]=$ret['scope_id'];
}

$res = mysql_query('select * from catalog_product_option');// get all product here which agains data inserted

$sort_orders=array(
                 1,
                 2,
                 3,
                 4);

//while ($ret = mysql_fetch_array($res)) {
foreach ($ress as $key => $ret) 
{
    //echo '<br>'.$ret[$key]["option_id"];
  foreach($stores as $locale=>$scopes){
      foreach($scopes as $scope){
          $query = "insert into catalog_product_option_title (option_id,store_id,title) values ($ret[option_id],$scope,'$option_titles[$locale]')";
          echo "$query<br>";
         $res1 = mysql_query($query);
      }
  }
  foreach($sort_orders as $order){
      $query = "insert into catalog_product_option_type_value (option_id,sort_order) values ($ret[option_id],$order)";
      echo "$query<br>";
      $res1 = mysql_query($query);
  }
}

echo "Populated catalog_product_option_title.<br>";
echo "Populated catalog_product_option_type_value.<br>";
$prices=array(
            0.00,//Standard (12 months)
            29.95,//Silver (12 months +loan phone + pic up)
            59.95,//Gold(12 months)
            89.95//Platinum (24 months +loan phone + pic up)
            );
$option_type_titles=array('en_US'=>array(
                                        'Standard (12 months).',
                                        'Silver (12 months +loan phone + pic up).',
                                        'Gold(12 months).',
                                        'Platinum (24 months +loan phone + pic up).'
                                        )
                            );
$res = mysql_query('select * from catalog_product_option_type_value');
$i = 0;
$j = count($prices)-1;


while ($ret = mysql_fetch_array($res)) {
  foreach($stores as $locale=>$scopes){
      foreach($scopes as $scope){
          $query = "insert into catalog_product_option_type_price (option_type_id,store_id,price,price_type) values ($ret[0],$scope,$prices[$i],'fixed')";
          echo "$query<br>";
          $res1 = mysql_query($query);
          $query = "insert into catalog_product_option_type_title (option_type_id,store_id,title) values ($ret[0],$scope,'{$option_type_titles[$locale][$i]}')";
          echo "$query<br>";
          $res1 = mysql_query($query);
      }
  }
  ($j==$i) ? $i= 0 : $i++ ;
}
echo "<br>Populated catalog_product_option_type_price.<br>";
echo "<br>Populated catalog_product_option_type_title.<br>";
?>
</pre>
</body>
</html>
```

dear this code is work and i check it . but this code when excute it will add this custom option with all products in your shop. you can change sort ordar and price and option values and also dropdown name . i think its work better.

Answer (score 0):

Try this, its working for me...

```
$eavSetup->addAttribute(CustomerMetadataInterface::ENTITY_TYPE_CUSTOMER,$attributeCode, [
    'type' => 'varchar',
    'label' => 'My Code',
    'input' => 'select',
    'source' => 'Magento\Eav\Model\Entity\Attribute\Source\Table',
    'required' => false,
    'visible' => true,
    'user_defined' => true,
    'sort_order' => 101,
    'position' => 101,
    'system' => 0,
    'option' =>
        array (
            'values' =>
                array(
                0 => 'January',
                1 => 'February',
                2 => 'March',
                3 => 'April',
                4 => 'May',
                5 => 'June',
                6 => 'July',
                7 => 'August',
                8 => 'September',
                9 => 'October',
                10 => 'November',
                11 => 'December'
            ),
        ),
]);
```